# Deploying Rails App on OVH shared hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I'm very new to the RoR world (3 days), and I'm facing with the following problem: I have a shared hosting on OVH and I have to deploy my Rails app on it, how can I do it?

I have only access to the folder containing the www directory with FTP protocol. No SSH connection.

There is only one hint to how to deploy it, but it doesn't works:
http://help.ovh.co.uk/RubyOnRails .
When I follow the instructions, the InstantRails does not create any .htaccess in the main root.

Some experienced with the Rails world can help me?

PS: OVH doesn't provides Passenger, Capistrano and so forth.

Thank u!!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience hosting a full-stack rails app on a shared hosting environment is next to impossible, there are many limitations towards the gems you can install and the web server you can use.

If you are able to then you should consider using a PaaS, like Heroku, Engineyard or OpenShift. Or if you are comfortable in linux environment - a VPS.

Comment: I tried with Heroku and it is very easy, but since OVH are saying that they are able to host Ruby projects and rails apps I wont to understand how to do it. Anyway thank you for your support!!

Comment: I recently tried a shared hosting as well. They noted, that they have a full RoR support. As it turned out, you could only install rails 2.3 and ruby 1.8.6 with few other available gems. They later stated that "CPanel has few limitation, which prevent developers from upgrading these versions".

Answer (score 0):

You could but you cannot install gem and this is the list of gem installed

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.1.8)
actionpack (4.1.8)
actionview (4.1.8)
activemodel (4.1.8)
activerecord (4.1.8)
activesupport (4.1.8)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
atomic (1.1.16)
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.7.4)
celluloid (0.15.2)
cmdparse (2.0.6)
coffee-rails (4.0.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
daemons (1.1.9)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.2.1)
ffi (1.9.6)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.9)
io-console (0.4.2)
jbuilder (2.1.3)
jquery-rails (3.1.2)
json (1.8.1)
listen (2.4.0)
log4r (1.1.10)
mail (2.6.1)
metaclass (0.0.4)
mime-types (1.25)
minitest (5.4.2, 4.7.5)
mocha (1.1.0)
multi_json (1.10.1)
ncursesw (1.4.8)
net-http-persistent (2.9)
oj (2.10.3)
polyglot (0.3.4)
psych (2.0.5)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.1.8)
railties (4.1.8)
rake (10.3.2, 10.1.0)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdoc (4.1.0)
RedCloth (4.2.9)
ruby-shadow (2.3.4)
sass (3.4.6)
sass-rails (4.0.3)
sdoc (0.4.1)
spring (1.1.3)
sprockets (2.12.3)
sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.9)
test-unit (2.1.5.0)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
timers (1.1.0)
treetop (1.4.15)
turbolinks (2.2.2)
tzinfo (1.1.0)
uglifier (2.5.3)
yajl-ruby (1.2.0)
```